# homogeneous first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

is there a method to solve $$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = f(x,y)$$, where $f(x,y)$ is a homogeneous function. I found some examples like $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2$ where it can be solved after converting it to Ricatti's equation.

thanks

Comment: Any particular $f(x, y)$ you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No as far as I know. There are certain particular cases that can be solved.

1. $f(x,y)$ homogeneous of degree $1$: change of variables $y=x\,u$.
2. $f(x,y) = g(a\,x+b\,y)$: change of variables $a\,x+b\,y=u$.
3. $f(x,y)=x^a\,y^b$: separeted variables.

But the equation $y'=x^a+y^a$, $a\ne0$, has an analytic solution (again afaik) only for $a=1$ and $a=2$ (in this last case in terms of Bessel functions.)